# sql query using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I have a query as follows

```
select VendorNumber,sum(EY_AmountIncl_LC)AmountIncl_LC ,SUm(EY_AmountExcl_LC)AmountExcl_LC,max(EY_datedocumented) Datedocumented
            ,stuff( (select distinct ','+dbo.table2.InvoiceStatus
                           from dbo.table2
                           where dbo.table2.VendorNumber = dbo.table2.VendorNumber 
                           for xml path('')
                          ), 1, 1, ''
                        ) as InvoiceStatus
from dbo.table2
group by VendorNumber
```

How do i write the same query using temptable in sql server management studio.can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 2):

First i would correct your `subquery` condition which should be referenced from outer query :

```
select VendorNumber, sum(EY_AmountIncl_LC) AmountIncl_LC, 
       max(EY_datedocumented) Datedocumented,
       stuff( (select distinct ','+t22.InvoiceStatus
               from dbo.table2 t22 -- create alias & use them 
               where t22.VendorNumber = t2.VendorNumber 
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as InvoiceStatus
from dbo.table2 t2 -- create alias & use them
group by VendorNumber;
```

Now, temp table has same functionality as base table, you just replace your base table name (`dbo.table2`) with temp table name (`#temp` whatever name you have).

Short Note about `alias` :

- You can use alias for table name as well as column name.
- COLUMN alias are used to make column headings in your result set easier to read.
- TABLE alias are used to shorten your SQL to make it easier to read or write, when you are performing a self join or using correlated `subquery`  (ie: listing the same table more than once in the `FROM` clause).

For more you can [visit](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/alias.php).

Comment: I am very new to sql and this concept can you help me in understanding what t22 and t2 are.I know very little things about aliases.can you help me in that.